# Register classes containing nested interfaces

Tags: c#, interface, nested, castle-windsor

I'm trying to register some classes that have some nested interfaces.
But for some reasons I can't seem to resolve the child interfaces.
I believe some code should make my intentions clear, so here we go:

```
public interface IDatasetContentMarshaller<TIn, TOut> : IDatasetContentMarshallerInfo
{
    TOut Marshall(CompanyDataset dataset, TIn content);
}

public interface IDatasetContentMarshallerInfo
{
    Type SourceType { get; }
    Type TargetType { get; }

    bool CanMarshal(object source);
    object Marshall(CompanyDataset dataset, object source);
}

public interface IGenericDatasetContentMarshaller
{
    TOut Marshall<TIn, TOut>(CompanyDataset dataset, TIn source);

    Func<CompanyDataset, TIn, TOut> GetMarshaller<TIn, TOut>();
}
```

The first interface with generic type parameters is used by code when the source and target type for conversion are known and fixed. And it is certain that there is a class which can do this conversion.

The child interface (`IDatasetContentMarshallerInfo`) contains some more information about the kind of conversion that is made. And the last interface is used to get the marshaller when the type of the input argument or return value are not known at compile time, or if there is no convertor/marshaller which can do this in one step. (Example 'string' to 'semester' may need 'string' to 'date' followed by 'date' to 'semester'. and it is the task of the generic content marshaller to find a chain marshallers to get the desired result.)

Any way the constructor for the `IGenericDatasetContentMarshaller` looks like this:

```
public GenericDatasetContentMarshaller(IDatasetContentMarshallerInfo[] marshallers)
{
    Marshallers = marshallers;
}
```

But I can't find a way to register this correctly.
Whatever I try I get an error telling me that the `IGenericDatasetContentMarshaller` could not be resolved.

The installer I wrote for this looks like this:

```
public class MarshallerInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new ArrayResolver(container.Kernel));

        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IDatasetContentMarshallerInfo>().LifestyleSingleton());

        container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<GenericDatasetContentMarshaller>()
            .Where(Helper.IsInNamespace("Q.Services.Marshallers.Dataset"))
            .LifestylePerWebRequest()
            .WithService.FirstInterface());

        var count = container.ResolveAll(typeof(IDatasetContentMarshallerInfo)).Length;
        Console.WriteLine("Items: " + count); // logs "Items: 0"
    }
}
```

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to use nested interfaces?
2. If so: how do you register those classes

Any help on the subject is welcome.

PS: It is possible to resolve the "top" using if I ask to inject a specific type like `IDatasetContentMarshaller<DateTime, Semester>`